# Unable to view apps on salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying out the new Salesforce1 app on my android mobile. I following the tutorial on the [salesforce1 developer guide](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_pages_test_it_task.htm).

I am unable to view the apps menu item on my salesforce1 app. I can view **Recent** and under that standard objects like Accounts, contacts etc.. But no apps like its shown in the developer guide
[image]

is there something that needs to be done to make the apps visible? Is it just me who is having this issue?

Comment: Do you have "Available for Salesforce mobile apps" enabled for your VF page?

Comment: @mast0r . Yes i have it enabled

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Peter is totally right, the concept of and "App" in S1 is a little different. 
Also, I would like to add a little bit more about a new metadata type that S1 introduced in this release ( I think Peter know about it too and he also recommended to me a good way to explain it :) )  , that we could consider the new view of "Apps".

If we make ourselves the question, what is having/ containing the App that we know at this moment?
What we know, an app can contain different tabs , that are pointing to different objects for example ( and sometimes tab related with VF pages), and what has a tab when you click on it? a default list view.
Then we could say that an App contain a list of tabs with default list views.

Well the new metadata type that S1 introduced is "Flexipage" , the flexipage will allow us to have diferent list views in only one page and also ( that the really nice part) have quick actions on it. Then this Flexipage , will be like a container where we will be able to put different list views, filtered list views or related to recent records, and quick global actions.

The Flexipage will appear like another tab in that picture and you can put it down or up ( using mobile administration).

To finish , I need to say that this metadata does not have a UI creation in this version of Salesforce, the new metadata is only possible to be create by deploying it into the org ( using ant commands or eclipse...)
Once the Flexipage is deployed into the org you will be able to find it in : Create -- > tabs --> Flexipage Tab , and you will be able to configure the icon too.

I leave you here a code example of flexipage :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>entityName</name>
                <value>Account</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>filterName</name>
                <value>MyAccounts</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>entityName</name>
                <value>Contact</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>filterName</name>
                <value>MyContacts</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:filterListCard</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>entityNames</name>
                <value>MyCustomObject__c</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>flexipage:recentItems</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>main</name>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>My new App</masterLabel>
    <quickActionList>
        <quickActionListItems>
            <quickActionName>flexiAction</quickActionName>
        </quickActionListItems>
    </quickActionList>
</FlexiPage>
```

I hope it is helpfull :)

Comment: You can find more info here : http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/flexible_pages_intro.htm

Comment: I have also written a blog around #flexipages that you can check out here: http://t.co/tEHG7tZEU2

Comment: I like the blog @KoenVM , You can also find useful the session that we did in Dreamforce '13 about Salesforce 1 and Publisher Actions : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEBJE3qwtXQ

Comment: Q&A tab is not showing up, any idea why it is not showing

Answer (score 7):

The concept of an "App" in S1 is a little different.

The App Picker control that we all know and love is not really there. And what you show as a list of "Apps" above isn't really...those are tabs.

So how does the UI gets surfaced in S1?

1. Is it a recently accessed sObject tab?
2. Is it a pinned sObject tab?
3. Is it a mobile-enabled VF tab?
4. It is a standard or custom publisher action?

For that particular tutorial you would be using item number 3 above.

The thing that I've encountered is that sometimes the list of "Apps" sometimes does not refresh. I have, at times had to completely log out of the S1 app and log back in. In the browser (accessing S1 through the one/one.app URL) I have somtimes needed to do a full page refresh.

But provided you've followed the steps of the tutorial, it should (eventually) appear.