# How do I customize the Salesforce1 menu?

Tags: salesforce1-app

How can I show my newly created app on the Salesforce1 mobile app? It doesn't appear as a menu option with Mobile Navigation. Also, how can I remove objects that are currently being shown?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Tiago. Have you read through the Salesforce1 guides? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I read salesforce 1 guide.
I want to place the object visible contacts, and create an action to create contacts and I'm not succeeding.

Answer (score 7):

By "Apps", they don't actually mean a collection of tabs (e.g. under "Create > Apps"), but rather a single Visualforce page that is "mobile enabled" that has a Visualforce tab. If you create a page that meets these qualifications, you can use it in Salesforce1. Note that this page can navigate to other visualforce pages, but the app shows only the first page.

Comment: More info on the steps it takes to get the page visible are in the [Salesforce1 Developer's Guide](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_pages_create_page_task.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But if I want to put custom objet visible is necessary to create a Visualforce page?

Comment: @Tiago No, the system should automatically show objects that the user frequently uses, so it's generally unnecessary to build Visualforce pages for that. See the Salesforce1 Developer's Guide for details (linked above).

Answer (score 4):

Might be you would like to use Flexipage.

If you want to see an "app" in mobile you will need to add it into Navigation Menu. Go to Mobile Administration --> Mobile Navigation.

But please Have a look to the thread below to get more info about Flexipages and App concept in SF1 .

["Unable to view apps on salesforce1 app"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/unable-to-view-apps-on-salesforce1-app/21859#21859)

Answer (score 2):

In order for custom objects to appear in the left navigation, there are two requirements:

1. The object must have a tab (Create > Tabs > Custom Tabs)
2. The tab must have been added to at least one app (Create > Apps)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/customize_s1_nav_about.htm).

Salesforce Desktop Apps and Apps section in the SF1 Nav are not equivalent.

Apps section in the SF1 Nav are counter-intuitively equivalent to Salesforce Desktop Tabs.

The link above shows you have to add Custom Tabs to the SF1 Nav menu. If the custom tab is a VF page, it must be enabled for mobile (see other responses).

A key caveat is that the first 4/5 tabs in the Selected column (in this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_pages_add_tab_to_nav_task.htm)) will show up almost as pinned tabs in the nav menu, while the other tabs will be put under the Apps section of the menu.

Comment: The landscape has changed radically since this question was posted. You should be less disparaging with your phrasing. I cleaned it up for you in this case.