# Where can I find flexipage documentation?

Tags: salesforce1-app, flexipages

Is there any other documentation about flexipages than the little info and tutorial in the [Salesforce1 App Developer Guide](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/flexible_pages_intro.htm) ?

We find this quite limited and are very interested in exploring this area more.

**Not so much looking for what flexipages are or how they can be uploaded/deployed into salesforce. Looking for a reference on the components possible, options, attributes of the xml content.. and so on.**

*update*: It appears no true documentation is published at this time. Please do still post an answer when such documentation gets published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late to answer, However I was also in need of documentation of Flexipage and found that it is refered as "[Lightning Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/flexible_page_about.htm)" in documentation. [This blog post](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/introduction-to-flexipage-in-salesforce1-and-deploying-it-using-workbench/) will help to explain more about it.

In nutshell, we use FLexipage to show components like Visualforce only in Salesforce1 application and not in Desktop version of Salesforce.

Answer (score 6):

I have been in touch with Salesforce (as a DFC author) on a somewhat related topic for last few days and I know that no additional public documentation (at least officially) exists on FlexiPages as of now. Having said that, I also know that there is a plan to publish more blog posts & DFC articles on Salesforce1 in January and I believe it would cover FlexiPages. As things stand, apart from the App Developer Guide, there's [this](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Salesforce1-Dev-Guide-Setup-Package) github repo authored by Sandeep Bhanot from Salesforce which provides similar info to links that have been quoted above.

Answer (score 3):

might be you will find some documentation in this link : [Metadata API Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm)

Also you can have a look to this answer:[view app in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/unable-to-view-apps-on-salesforce1-app/21859#21859)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not so much looking for what flexipages are or how they can be uploaded. Looking for a reference on the components possible, options, attributes of the xml content. I guess this doesn't exist yet and that we'll have to wait.

Comment: Hi @Sdry, I got your point. I'm afraid that that functionality/Options are not available yet, but in conversations with SF they commented that are thinking on it and might be will be available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links

in metadata Api document

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_flexipage.htm

in SOAP API developers guide:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_describeflexipages.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_describeflexipages.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not feel this answers the question.